# mongoose + nodejs push array to database

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJS + Mongoose and having trouble pushing an array to my database via mongoose.

I have the following schema:

```
const StudentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String
},
quizzes: [{
    quiz: String,
    answers: []
  }]
});
```

What I'm trying to do is have an array of quiz objects in which the quiz number is shown and the array of answers for that particular quiz.

When I create a new user, the student object looks like this in mongoose:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId(id here),
"name" : "John",
"quizzes" : [ ],
"__v" : 0
}
```

The function I'm using to update the quiz array:

```
module.exports.addQuiz = function(student_id, answers, callback){
Student.findByIdAndUpdate(
    student_id,
    {$push: {"quizzes": {answers: answers}}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, model) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

}

And this is my route which calls the function whenever the endpoint is hit with a student_id, which will then be used to find the student and push to the array

```
router.post('/quiz/:student_id', (req, res, next) => {

var student_id = req.params.id;
var answers = req.body.answers;

Student.addQuiz(student_id, answers, (err, answers) => {
    //error handling
 })
});
```

I'm trying to test this by sending a post request to /quiz/:student_id with an id of a student in my database with the following JSON sent in the body:

```
[{
    "quiz": "Quiz 1",
    "answers": ["Answer 1", "Answer 2"]
}]
```

Although when I try this it ends up getting hung somewhere and the request never completes - I also get a "null" in the console.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: You need to send response to the request, with for exemple `res.json()`.

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't work.

Comment: What specifically _doesn't work_ ?

Comment: I managed to get it working. The issue was it wasn't reading the id parsed from the url. var student_id = req.params.id; should have been var student_id = req.params.student_id;